# Parâmetros opcionais na Rota do Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estou passando parâmetros numa Rota usando Laravel 5.8 assim:

```
Route::get('/cursos/{id_categoria_curso}/{id_atuacao_area}', 'SiteController@cursosFiltro')->name('cursos');
```

Quero fazer com que o Controller execute se os valores forem passados ou não. Por exemplo: Um link que irá passar os Dois parâmetros, outro link que vai passar apenas Um e um terceiro link que não vai passar nenhum?

Tem como fazer isso num na Rota e no Controller ou vou ter que fazer 3 Controllers um para cada situação?

> Sempre vai carregar a mesma View. Tendo ou não parâmetros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só colocar um ponto de interrogação no final do parâmetro para torna-lo [opcional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-optional-parameters):

```
Route::get('/cursos/{id_categoria_curso?}/{id_atuacao_area?}', 'SiteController@cursosFiltro')->name('cursos');
```

Ainda assim, no seu *controller* você precisa declarar esses parâmetros:

```
public function cursosFiltro($id_categoria_curso = null, $id_atuacao_area = null)
{
    // faz alguma lógica com os parâmetros 
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma agora ta assim: Se passar os dois parâmetros funciona. Se passar 1 ou nenhum não carrega os cursos. 

o filtro ta assim:
$cursos = Curso::where('id_categoria_curso', $id_categoria_curso)
            ->where('id_atuacao_area', $id_atuacao_area)
            ->get();

        return view('site.cursos.cursos',
            compact('cursos', 'categorias', 'areas'));

Comment: ao você precisa trabalhar a lógica do seu controller.

Comment: eu respondi minha pergunta com uma dúvida no IF. Você pode me ajudar?

Comment: nesse caso seria uma nova pergunta @JunioAraujo

Comment: relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1682/o-que-fazer-quando-o-o-p-muda-sua-pergunta/1684#1684